# How to do the jUnit testing

Tags: java, junit, junit3

I am brand new to jUnit testing and I do not know how it works, I tried to go through some tutorials online but couldn't understand much. So I am posting my code and the skeleton of the testClass, so how would the testClass be modified in this case, so that I can understand how jUnit works.

**the method that I want to test:**

```
public String quickSortArray(String numbers, String indexNumber) throws NumberFormatException, Exception{

                String[] data = numbers.split(";");
                int index = parseInt(indexNumber);
                int[] inputNum = new int[data.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    inputNum[i] = parseInt(data[i]);

                }
                Set<Integer> removeDuplicates = new HashSet<Integer>();
                for (int j = 0; j < inputNum.length; j++) {
                    removeDuplicates.add(inputNum[j]);
                }
                int[] finalSortArray = new int[removeDuplicates.size()];
                int k = 0;
                for (Integer move : removeDuplicates) {
                    finalSortArray[k++] = move;
                }
                Arrays.sort(finalSortArray);
                if (finalSortArray.length < index) {
                    return "The index cannot be greater than the non-repeated numbers";                    
                } else {
                    int result=finalSortArray[finalSortArray.length-index];                    
                    return String.valueOf(result);
                }
            }
```

The testClass generated by the IDE:

```
/**
     * Test of quickSortArray method, of class quickSort.
     */
    public void testQuickSortArray() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("quickSortArray");
        String numbers = "";
        String indexNumber = "";
        quickSort instance = new quickSort();
        String expResult = "";
        String result = instance.quickSortArray(numbers, indexNumber);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }
```

So I just want to know how the testClass should be written that my method is tested for its functionality. I would really appreciate all the help

What the method basically does is from an array of numbers separated by semicolon it first converts them to int and then removes the duplicates and then finds the Nth largest number. N is the index in this case.

Here is some manual data, I dont want the person answering to go through the trouble of calculating this as well:
expResult=57;
numbers="12;57;65"
index="2";

expResult=39;
numbers="09;78;45;39;05"
index="3";

I just want to know how to use this in the code.

Comment: You could run a coverage.

Comment: 1) Create test data. 2) Manually calculate the answer for that test data. 3) Verify that the method returns the same answer. 4) Figure out corner cases. P.S. why is the method called "quick sort" when it does no such thing?

Comment: @GGrec ?? What is that, as I said I am new to jUnit. Don;t know anything.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have posted the manual data in the question, could you please edit my testClass and post an answer, that would clear both the algo and usage of jUnit

Comment: @BoristheSpider And I also dont know what corner cases are?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I edited the code in the quickSort.java file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that your class looks like this

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class X {

    public String quickSortArray(String numbers, String indexNumber) throws NumberFormatException, Exception{

        String[] data = numbers.split(";");
        int index = parseInt(indexNumber);
        int[] inputNum = new int[data.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            inputNum[i] = parseInt(data[i]);

        }
        Set<Integer> removeDuplicates = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int j = 0; j < inputNum.length; j++) {
            removeDuplicates.add(inputNum[j]);
        }
        int[] finalSortArray = new int[removeDuplicates.size()];
        int k = 0;
        for (Integer move : removeDuplicates) {
            finalSortArray[k++] = move;
        }
        Arrays.sort(finalSortArray);
        if (finalSortArray.length < index) {
            return "The index cannot be greater than the non-repeated numbers";                    
        } else {
            int result=finalSortArray[finalSortArray.length-index];                    
            return String.valueOf(result);
        }
    }

    private int parseInt(String indexNumber) {
        return Integer.parseInt(indexNumber);
    } 
}
```

I think you could write some JUnit test like this

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;


public class XTest {

    @Test
    public void testQuickSortArray1() throws NumberFormatException, Exception {
        String numbers="12;57;65";
        String index="2";
        String result = new X().quickSortArray(numbers, index);
        assertEquals("57",result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testQuickSortArray2() throws NumberFormatException, Exception {
        String numbers="09;78;45;39;05";
        String index="3";
        String result = new X().quickSortArray(numbers, index);
        assertEquals("39",result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What the method basically does is from an array of numbers separated
>   by semicolon it **first** converts them to int **and then** removes the
>   duplicates **and then** finds the Nth largest number. N is the index in
>   this case

First step would be to split your method into 3 (or more) so you can test each aspect individually.

The idea of unit tests is that the assembly works if each individual brick works.

Your test then become much simpler:

```
@Test
public void parsesSimpleArray(){
    assertThat( parser.parse("12;57;65") ).eq(new int[]{12,57,65});
}

@Test
public void parseIgnoresEmptyStrings(){
    // or whatever your desired behavior should be
    assertThat( parser.parse("12;;65") ).eq(new int[]{12,65});
}
```

etc...

Comment: Do you want me to break my quickSortArray into three different methods??

Comment: Yes. It's doing too much, which means testing boundary conditions or complex behaviors is going to be difficult. Split it into simple methods doing one thing and one thing only. If you need a convenience API combining parsing, deduplication and sorting, that's fine - but you don't actually need to test that one as the only thing it should do is call sort(deduplicate(parse()), and you already having sort(), deduplicate() and parse() under individual tests.

Comment: To expand on my answer: when something is hard to test, it often is because it's doing too much, relies on too much state, or isn't great code. The answer in that case is to fix the code so it is easier to test rather than come up with a complex brittle test. This validation of design in the small is a major benefit of unit testing.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for all the explanation. Upvoted.. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Split your method into smaller testable methods: here you have a combination of input parsing (from string to some sort of collection) and probably sorting (which is difficult to follow though) -- you want to test those functionalities separately
2. Define "test cases" that you want to test, first not programmatically, but conceptually. For example you want to test if the method does not fail for empty data, works fine on sorted data, on data of size 1, of odd and even size, on a number of repeated values etc
3. Define scenarios where the method should throw an exception and write test method for that annotating them as `@Test(expected=IllegalArgumentException.class)`
4. Per test case implement a test method in the following form (this particular piece of code may not be compilable :)

   ```
   @Test
   public testPresortedValues()
   {
       List<Integer> data = Lists.newArrayList(1, 1, 1, 2, 25, 30);
       List<Integer> expected = Lists.newArrayList(1, 1, 1, 2, 25, 30);
       Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
       sorter.sort(data);
       for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
       {
            Asser.assertEquals(data.get(i), expected.get(i);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Sir I want to just understand how this works, so I would really appreciate it if you could use my manual data and edit my testClass so that I can understand.

Comment: I am afraid my explanations and the example are comprehensive enough. Refactor your code first (this was also suggested in the other answer), post your updated code and maybe then somebody will pick up a task of providing an actual test case, maybe I will then. In fact @ptyx has already provided you with two examples, I would not do it that way directly on strings, but what more do you want?

Comment: No problem I will see what I can do